# ImageView in Recycleview issues : image not showing

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-imageview

Context: One of the functionality in the app I am developing is picking images from a Photo Picker. The images picked appear in an ImageView attached to Recyclerview. Before now all images picked do show on the ImageView.

Issue: However, recently, I discovered that after integrating the app with Amazon S3, some images don't show or appear on the ImageView when picked from a Photo Picker.

Error displayed: The error displayed is :

"Request threw uncaught throwable "
"java.lang.SecurityException: Calling uid ( 10520 ) does not have permission to access picker uri: "

I have searched for similar issues here but none was helpful. Has anyone any idea what the issue could be.